# HTML/CSS List style help :S

Tags: html, css, list, styles

I made a list and using the ul tag added an id, but the only way I can seem ot get my list to be styled is by actually styling the ul and li tags but if i do that all my lists will look the same. If you dont understand heres the code -

```
 <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
                <li>Premium</li>
                <li>FAQ</li>
                <li>Disclaimer</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="login">
                <li>Login</li>
                <li>-</li>
                <li>Register</li>
            </ul>
```

But I dont want both of these lists to be styled that way I want them to be different and the only way I can get the style to take effect is to do -

```
#navigation{
color:#808080;
float:left;
margin-top:50px;
font-family:"Myriad Pro", Times, serif;
}

#login{
color:#808080;
float:right;
margin-top:50px;
font-family:"Myriad Pro", Times, serif;
}

ul li{
display:inline;
text-decoration:none;
padding:15px;
 }
```

So my question is how can I apply padding 15px to the navigation list and not to the login list I tried putting it in the navigation css code but it did nothing :(

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do it is to put the generic styles first , then the more specific styles after

```
ul li {
  display:inline;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#navigation, #login {
  color:#808080;
  margin-top:50px;
  font-family:"Myriad Pro", Times, serif;
}

#navigation {
  float:left;
}

#login{
  float:right;
}

#navigation li {
  padding:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
#navigation li {
   ... your styles
}

#login li {
   ... your different styles
}
```

You can also first set default li styles, and overwrite/add to them for li in #navigation like this:

```
li {
   ... default styles
}

#navigation li {
   ... styles for navigation list, on top of the default ones
}
```

Comment: Hey thats great it fixed it but it changed one thing it swapped the list around its now being displayed back to front Eek

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the css descendant selector - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors :

```
#navigation li{
    display:inline;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px;
}

#login li{
    display:inline;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```